# Passing function( has call back function(has argument)) as object attribute

Tags: javascript, callback, jsobject

i have showProfile function which is accept callback function .

The callback function has also an argment which is an object.

```
showProfile(call_back_fn)
```

invoke it :

```
showProfile(function(obj){console.log(obj)})
```

I want to set this function as an attribute to Person Object :

```
    function Person(name,age,showProfile){
       this.name=name ;
        this.age=age;
       /*
        this.showProfile=showProfile ???
                 OR
       this.prototype.showProfile=showProfile ???
               OR What ??    
*/

              return this;        
    }
```

then ,to create a Person object :

```
 var p=new Person('Abdennour',23,fnshowProfile);
```

How can i make this  function(showProfile) as an object attribute .and if it's possible , how to pass its argument(wich is a call back function) ? 
Then , How to Call `fnshowProfile` which is in the snippet above.

**UPDATE**

OtherWise, if i create a Person object as follwoing :

```
 var p=new Person('Abdennour',23,showProfile());
```

How can i access to showProfile to add a callback function as argument:
an d then , how can i execute showProfile from `p` object.

Comment: This is a little unclear, could you maybe jsFiddle something up for this?

Comment: i edit the title of question :Passing function( has call back function(has argument)) as object attribute .

Comment: See also , words written after Update

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found it : 
**Demo** :http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/5vNQ5/

```
callbackshowProfile=function(obj){
    alert(obj['field1']);

}

showProfile=function(cfn){
     cfn();
}


function Person(name,age,shfn,callback){
 this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.shfn=shfn;
    this.callback=callback;
    return this;
}
```

Create a Person object :

```
var pp=new Person('Abdennour',13,showProfile,callbackshowProfile)
```

To call showProfile which has callback function as parameter, which is has an object as parameter.

```
pp.shfn(pp.callback.bind(null,{field1:'My field 1'}))
```